# GraphQL isomorfic model

Tags: angular, graphql, graphql-js

I plan to use Angular2 with GraphQL. I'm looking for a way to use GraphQL model on the client to dynamically build queries. How can I implement this idea?

GraphQL model looks like

```
exports default new GrapqhQLObjectType({
name: 'User',
description: 'A user type in our application',
fields: () => {
  _id:{
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
  },
  name:{
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
  },
  surname:{
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
  },
  age: {
    type: GraphQLInt
  }
    }
  });
```

All dataTypes import from GraphQL.JS

I want to validate data datatypes on client from this GraphQL model.

GraphQL query looks like

```
mutation RootMutation {
editUser (name: "Bjarne", age:64) {
    name
    surname
    _id
    age
}
}
```

I changed in Angular2 data age value and I would like to request above was generated automatically

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? It could make it possible for people knowing Angular2 but not GraphQL or vice versa to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to introspect the schema with GraphQL’s introspection query sent in as a string (shown below). You can perform type validation in the native app that way by cross-checking the type that’s returned from the schema. Other than that, you can send in a request using GraphiQL (https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) to make sure your query/mutation is correct before you include it in your app.

```
query IntrospectionQuery {
 __schema {
 queryType { name }
 mutationType { name }
 subscriptionType { name }
 types {
 ...FullType
 }
 directives {
 name
 description
 locations
 args {
 ...InputValue
 }
 }
 }
}
fragment FullType on __Type {
 kind
 name
 description
 fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
 name
 description
 args {
 ...InputValue
 }
 type {
 ...TypeRef
 }
 isDeprecated
 deprecationReason
 }
 inputFields {
 ...InputValue
 }
 interfaces {
 ...TypeRef
 }
 enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
 name
 description
 isDeprecated
 deprecationReason
 }
 possibleTypes {
 ...TypeRef
 }
}
fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
 name
 description
 type { ...TypeRef }
 defaultValue
}
fragment TypeRef on __Type {
 kind
 name
 ofType {
 kind
 name
 ofType {
 kind
 name
 ofType {
 kind
 name
 }
 }
 }
}
```